# Which version of JSP is the latest?

Tags: jsp

I downloaded `jsp-api` from `https://repo.maven.apache.org/`,
I found the versions were weird.

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Version 2.2 has 3 packages:

```
javax.servlet.jsp
javax.servlet.jsp.el
javax.servlet.jsp.tagext
```

Version 2.1 has 4 packages:

```
javax.el
javax.servlet.jsp
javax.servlet.jsp.el
javax.servlet.jsp.tagext
```

Some classes are deprecated in `javax.servlet.jsp` package, like `javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException` which is replaced by `javax.el.ELException`.

However, in version 2.2, there isn't `javax.el` package.
Why does `javax.el` package disappear in version 2.2?

In addition, I searched `jsp-api` in `http://mvnrepository.com` and I found the version ***2.3.1***. After downloading it, I found it was the same as the version 2.2 downloaded before.

In the end, it seems that I found the official website`https://jsp.java.net/`. It doesn't explain the version of `jsp-api`. It only mentions the version2.1.

I'm confused with these versions. Could anyone give me some explanation about the version of JSP?

Answer (score 2):

Latest version is ***2.3.3*** (look [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api)).

Technically, JSP 2.3 is the second [*maintenance release*](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index2.html) of JSP 2.1.